# error: request for member 'q' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'const int'

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

A part of my code,

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long ull;
typedef long long ll;

#define mod 1e9+7
#define eps 1e-9 

#define mp make_pair
#define pb push_back

#define x first
#define y second


    bool intersect1d(ll l1, ll r1, ll l2, ll r2) {
        if (l1 > r1)
            swap(l1, r1);
        if (l2 > r2)
            swap(l2, r2);
        return max(l1, l2) <= min(r1, r2) + EPS;
    }

    int vec(const pair<ll,ll>& a, const pair<ll,ll>& b, const pair<ll,ll>& c) {
        double s = (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (b.y - a.y) * (c.x - a.x);
        return abs(s) < eps ? 0 : s > 0 ? +1 : -1;
    }

    bool intersect(const seg& a,const seg& b)
    {
        return intersect1d(a.p.x, a.q.x, b.p.x, b.q.x) &&
               intersect1d(a.p.y, a.q.y, b.p.y, b.q.y) &&
               vec(a.p, a.q, b.p) * vec(a.p, a.q, b.q) <= 0 &&
               vec(b.p, b.q, a.p) * vec(b.p, b.q, a.q) <= 0;
    }

    struct seg
    {
        pair<ll,ll> p,q;
        seg(const pair<ll,ll>& pr1 , const pair<ll,ll>& pr2)
        {
            p = pr1;
            q = pr2;
        }
    };
```

On compiling this gives the following error

```
error: request for member 'q' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'const int'
            vec(b.p, b.q, a.p) * vec(b.p, b.q, a.q) <= 0;
```

What is causing this?
Is there anything wrong with my struct constructor?
 I don't see const int being used anywhere? Any hints would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Related: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.

Comment: This is the reason why one letter names are *bad*.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen,still it is not the cause of error, is it?

Comment: Move `struct seg` to top.

Comment: @FaisalM, that fixed it. Thanks. Why is that? (Post this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always solve compiler errors from the top. One compiler error often creates more errors, when compiler tries to compile the rest of the code.

The first error you get is

```
prog.cc:45:26: error: 'seg' does not name a type
   45 |     bool intersect(const seg& a,const seg& b)
      |                          ^~~
```

Compiler doesn't know what `seg` is. You should declare `struct seg` *before* it is used.

```
struct seg
{
    pair<ll,ll> p,q;
    seg(const pair<ll,ll>& pr1 , const pair<ll,ll>& pr2)
    {
        p = pr1;
        q = pr2;
    }
};

bool intersect(const seg& a,const seg& b)
{
    return intersect1d(a.p.x, a.q.x, b.p.x, b.q.x) &&
           intersect1d(a.p.y, a.q.y, b.p.y, b.q.y) &&
           vec(a.p, a.q, b.p) * vec(a.p, a.q, b.q) <= 0 &&
           vec(b.p, b.q, a.p) * vec(b.p, b.q, a.q) <= 0;
}
```